# True or False The image of the unit square under one-to-one matrix operator is a square

Tags: linear-algebra

The image of the unit square under one-to-one matrix operator is a square is this true or false

Answer (score 3):

False. Consider the dilation

$$\begin{pmatrix} a \ 0 \\ 0 \ b \end{pmatrix}$$

where $a \neq b$.